# Core Animation formula for movement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a formula for setting x and y of an object at every frame.
In a classic `for (i=0; i < x; i++)` loop, I can bind it to the `i` value and calculate x and y values based on the current value of `i` that represents the passing of time.

I intended to use it with a NSTimer object and update the coordinate points at every tick, but I've seen that NSTimer is descouraged for animations.

Can I do the same with Core Animation? Instead of the standard "from here to there in given seconds", I would need a method to "update the position with this formula".

Comment: Good question..I would like to know too..

Comment: I haven't used it myself, and hopefully someone can give you more details, but [`CAKeyframeAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006672-SW11) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can model your function with a cubic Bézier curve, you can create a custom `CAMediaTimingFunction` instance and assign it to the animation's `timingFunction` property.

If a Bézier curve does not work, a `CAKeyframeAnimation` might indeed work.